# WPF RichTextBox seems to add in hidden padding

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

This is driving me nuts. I'm writing a text highlighter, which ultimately calls the code:

```
TextPointer caret = textBox.CaretPosition;
TextPointer contentStart = textBox.Document.ContentStart;

TextPointer highlightStart = contentStart.GetPositionAtOffset(startPosition + 1, LogicalDirection.Forward);
TextPointer highlightEnd = contentStart.GetPositionAtOffset(endPosition + 2, LogicalDirection.Forward);

textBox.Selection.Select(highlightStart, highlightEnd);
textBox.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(textElementProperty, value);
textBox.Selection.Select(caret, caret);

textBox.CaretPosition = caret;
```

The actual code itself works fine.... once. The problem is that once it highlights, it's like the `RichTextBox` is adding in hidden padding around my highlighting such that when I run my `Regex` over the text, the `Regex` returns the correct offsets, but then it doesn't map correctly to the right letter in the `RichTextBox`. So for example, if I were to highlight the word 'fox' as in:

The quick brown **fox** jumped over the lazy dog.

The word 'fox' would be highlighted correctly, but then if I were to change 'dog' to fox it would show up like:

The quick brown **fox** jumped over the laz **y fo** ox.

Removing the first 'fox' however would correct the latter version so that it would read:

The quick brown dog jumped over the lazy **fox**.

It's almost like the `RichTextBox` is adding in some padding which I can't account for when doing the text scan.

**Update**

I found a hacky solution to the problem. But, it only seems to further confirm my suspicions. If I apply the coloration *in reverse* this seems to fix it, as in:

```
protected override void TextChanged(TextChangedEventArgs args) {
    var matches = regex.Matches(base.Text)
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(match => new {
            Start = match.Index,
            End = match.Index + match.Length
        }).Reverse();

    foreach (var match in matches) {
        Colorize(match.Start, match.End, TextElement.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Blue);
    }

}
```

Which seems like I shouldn't have to do it. Seriously look like it's adding padding or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TextPointer API is counting not just characters but *symbols* which can include opening and closing tags etc. See the remarks section here on MSDN on what is counted as a symbol
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598662.aspx

So when you add in some formatting it will throw out symbol offsets you have saved later in the text. You would have to apply formatting search from there on again etc. Or doing it in reverse also works.

Comment: I thought about this for a while, and it seems like the best way to do it is to get the position markers all at once, and then apply the highlighting all at once in order to sidestep all of the padding/shifting. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You might want to check out the TextRange stuff [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.textrange.aspx). From memory, if you set up a myTextRange = TextRange(textPointer1, textPointer2) it will maintain its relative position in the face of edits. You can apply styling to it with myTextRange.ApplyPropertyValue(...)

Comment: Yeah, that's effectively what I did. I precalc all of the `TextPointer`/`TextRange` positions, and then just apply the changes afterwards. Although `RichTextBox` is so ridiculously slow I'm tempted to just rewrite the functionality I need by hand.